# What are the differences between 0, int() and int{}?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, zero, compile-time-constant

As `int()` and `int{}` are **constant** expressions of value equal to `0`, I thought they are equivalent and interchangeable, thus compilers must treat them equally. For example,

```
 int a[0];      //error: zero-sized array not allowed in ISO C++
 int b[int()];  //error: zero-sized array not allowed in ISO C++
 int c[int{}];  //error: zero-sized array not allowed in ISO C++
```

But it seems there are some corner cases where they're not interchangeable.

- When initializing a pointer:

  ```
  int *p = 0;     //ok
  int *q = int(); //error - by clang only
  int *r = int{}; //error - by gcc and clang both
  ```

  See [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a1002b40490e5ff) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf1763fd8bbbd64a) messages. I suspect this is a bug in both compilers, as I expect them to be interchangeable in this context, but I would be glad to be proven wrong. :-)
- When passing to class template:

  ```
  template<int N> struct X{};

  X<0>      x1; //ok
  X<int{}>  x2; //ok (same as X<0>)
  X<int()>  x3; //error
  ```

  See [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec2356bb1af66581) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4de0ee8be98d8251) messages.

  I find the syntax `X<int()>` quite familiar as I've seen (and probably used) the similar syntax before, such as in `std::function<int()>`, the template argument `int()` is expected to be *function type*  (instead of `0`) taking no argument and returning `int`. But I want to know the section of the spec which says in this context `int()` is to be treated as function *type* and is not equivalent to `int{}` which is always `0`.

Comment: So this is basically a "grep the standard for me" question, right?

Comment: Do you expect the relevant standard text to be in a different place from the text that defines the "most vexing parse"?

Comment: I like it too.  It's a very good question---my impression is that the standard isn't clear about it (but I'm still studying it).

Comment: @SteveJessop Do you think the most vexing parse applies to any of the cases here?  I don't see it, except maybe for `X<int()>`.  And even then, I think the compiler first finds `X`, and so knows that it's not looking for a type.

Comment: @SteveJessop: *I think* I know the context of most vexing parse : when a syntax can be interpreted as two ways : function declaration and (named) object declation, then function declaration is preferred. But I don't think that applies here. I don't see named object here. So I am unable to relate. :(

Comment: Regarding `X<int()>`: **14.3 [temp.arg]** "In a *template-argument*, an ambiguity between a *type-id* and an *expression* is resolved to a *type-id*, regardless
of the form of the corresponding *template-parameter*."

Comment: @Nawaz You don't need named objects.  But you do need a context where a declaration would be legal.  I think this excluded the "initialization of a pointer".

Comment: @JamesKanze: it was `X<int()>` I was thinking of, I couldn't remember the wording of the vexation so wasn't sure whether or not it would imply parsing as a function type here. Apologies that my remark wasn't helpful.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ohh, then I've to see it again, because so far I've seen most vexing parse comes into picture when *name* is involved, be it name of a function or object.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes.  That one seems questionable to me, too.  C++ generally tries to avoid requiring semantic information to drive the parsing.  (It doesn't always succeed.)  In the case of `X<int()>`, the _grammatical context_ allows a type declaration, so unless the standard requires the compiler to take semantic information (the fact that the template parameter isn't a type parameter) into account, it's a type declaration (and another instance of the most vexing parse.

Comment: The real question, of course, is whether `int()` or `int{}` are
constant expressions.  The text in §15.9 doesn't line up easily
with the rest of the standard: it speaks in part about "invoking
a `constexpr` constructor, but there is no expression which
"invokes a constructor" (and `int` doesn't have a constructor).
Formally, `int()` and `int{}` are "Explicit type conversions".

Comment: A value initialized `int` and the literal `0` are different things

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: They're constant expressions, aren't they? If so, in what ways they're different as per the spec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expressions `int()` and `int{}` are both constant expression prvalues of integer type that evaluate to zero, and are therefore interchangeable with the literal `0` in any context that requires an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type which evaluates to zero.

Both expressions satisfy the requirements for a constant expression as specified in *5.19 Constant Expressions [expr.const]*.

Regarding `X<int()>`, the standard specifies that `int()` is not interpreted as an expression in this context:

> #### 14.3 Template arguments [temp.arg]
>
> In a *template-argument*, an ambiguity between a *type-id* and an *expression* is resolved to a *type-id*, regardless of the form of the corresponding *template-parameter*.

Regarding pointer conversions:

> #### 4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]
>
> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero
>   or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Based on the above paragraph, both `int()` and `int{}` are null pointer constant expressions. This points to a (very minor) compiler bug, although there is an open Defect Report ([903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html)) which may lead to this paragraph changing:

> There was a strong consensus among the CWG that only the literal 0 should be considered a null pointer constant, not any arbitrary zero-valued constant expression as is currently specified.

The following wording deals with the value of the expression `int()`:

> #### 8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]
>
> **To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:**
>
> [*omitted clauses which don't apply*]
>
> — **if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression,
>   converted to T**
>
> [...]
>
> **To value-initialize an object of type T means:**
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
>   default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>
> [*omitted clauses which don't apply*]
>
> — **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**
>
> **An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.**

And for the value of `int{}`:

> #### 8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]
>
> **List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:**
>
> — If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is
>   value-initialized.
>
> [*omitted clauses which don't apply*]
>
> — **Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.**

All quotes from C++ Working Draft Standard N3337.

Comment: For the definition of *prvalue*, see **3.10 [basic.lval]**. This definition includes literal `0`.

Comment: Change of CWG opinion then, because the question which integral expressions are valid null pointer constants has come up before. And back then we explicitly allowed `false` as a NPC. Not `1-1`, though, as this predates `constexpr`, and we therefore had no way to express what was "const enough".

Comment: @MSalters There's an additional note in DR 903: *Concerns were raised at the Portland (October, 2012) meeting that the value false has been used in existing code as a null pointer constant, and such code would be broken by this change. This issue has been returned to "review" status to allow discussion of whether to accommodate such code or not.*